# replacing part of string using sed

Tags: replace, sed, between

I have this big file 1,000,000+ lines, which includes some memory data. For a certain use I need to convert g to mb, example:

```
DateAndTime#15/03/15 07:57:07
**********************
top - 07:57:27 up 2 days, 15:28, 18 users,  load average: 4.65, 3.15, 2.11
Tasks: 774 total,   2 running, 771 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s): 12.8 us,  2.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 83.5 id,  1.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  16327128 total, 16119192 used,   207936 free,   177868 buffers
KiB Swap: 36060156 total,    78552 used, 35981604 free.  6570548 cached Mem

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 26636 fpd       20   0 9987.4m 6.307g  47728 S   0.0 40.5 192:07.10 AppExe
 29019 fpd       20   0 1752832 785848  45652 S  77.0  4.8  17:32.74 python
```

to:

```
 26636 fpd       20   0 9987.4m 6307m  47728 S   0.0 40.5 192:07.10 AppExe
```

The problem is that the file is built in a non comfortable to use structure, the x.xxxG needs to be found first and only than replaced, thus taking a whole lot of time (via readline), also the rest of the file should stay the same.

Comment: i can't able to understand your logic.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "the x.xxxG needs to be found first and only than replaced, thus taking a whole lot of time (via readline)". Please edit your question directly to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works on Linux and OSX/BSD systems:

```
sed -E 's/(^| )([0-9]).([0-9]{3})g( |$)/\1\2\3m\4/g' infile > outfile
```

It makes certain assumptions:

- any field of the form `d.dddg` (where `d` is a decimal digit) should be replaced (possibly even multiple occurrences on a single line - remove the `g` after the last `/` to replace at most *one* per line)
- fields are space-delimited

If, by contrast, actual calculations need to be performed, `awk` is your friend.

Comment: @Lev: My pleasure. For the benefit of both respondents and future readers: If an answer _solves_ your problem, please _accept it_ by clicking the large check mark next to it; if you find an answer _helpful_, please _up-vote_ it by clicking the up-arrow icon. (You may do both.)